# Find the value of $\nu$ so that $n^\nu (1-X_{(n)})$ converges in distribution

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, convergence, beta-distribution

Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ be iid. If $X_i \sim Beta(1,\beta)$, find the value of $\nu$ so that $n^\nu (1-X_{(n)})$ converges in distribution.

My thoughts:

Since $X_{(n)} \to 1$ in probability, I was thinking I can use this information. However, I don't really see how this can be important.

I would like to learn how to approach these convergence problems. When you look at this problem, what are your initial thoughts? Can you please take me through the thought process?

**Work in Progress**

First step: Find CDF. This is the first step because we can use either CDFs or MGFs to show convergence; however, MGFs are not as powerful for location-scale transformations.

Let $Y=n^\nu(1-X_{(n)})$. Then, $F_Y(y)=P(n^\nu(1-X_{(n)} \le y) = 1 - P(X_{(n)} < 1- \frac{y}{n^\nu})=1-F_{X_{(n)}}(1-\frac{y}{n^\nu})$ $=1-F_x(1-\frac{y}{n^\nu})^n.$

Now, we know that $X \sim Beta(1, \beta)$. So, we can find this last statement by differentiating both sides.

Comment: First step is to find the CDF of $n^\nu (1-X_{(n)})$.

Comment: Dose $X_{(n)}$ reprsent $nth$ order statistic? You can refer to convergence in distribution and some examples by this link: https://www.statlect.com/asymptotic-theory/convergence-in-distribution

Comment: @StubbornAtom I added some work using the first step. However, I can't get a nice form by differentiating both sides of the equality. What do you think?

Comment: No need to differentiate to get the pdf. Try taking the limit $n\to\infty$ from the CDF itself. This is where the value of $\nu$ comes into play.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Such as $F_Y(y)=1-F_X(1-\frac{y}{n^\nu})^n \to e^{-y}$ if $\nu =1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDF of $X_1$  is

$$P(X_1\le y)=\begin{cases}0&,\text{ if }y<0 \\ 1-(1-y)^\beta &,\text{ if }0<y<1 \\1&,\text{ if }y>1\end{cases}$$

Therefore verify that the CDF of $n^\nu(1-X_{(n)})$ is

\begin{align}
P(n^\nu(1-X_{(n)})\le y)&=P\left(X_{(n)}\ge 1-\frac{y}{n^\nu}\right)
\\&=1-P\left(X_{(n)}\le 1-\frac{y}{n^\nu}\right)
\\&=1-\left\{P\left(X_1\le 1-\frac{y}{n^\nu}\right)\right\}^n
\\&=\begin{cases}1&,\text{ if }y>n^\nu \\ 1-\left(1-\frac{y^\beta}{n^{\nu\beta}}\right)^n &,\text{ if }0<y<n^\nu \\0&,\text{ if }y<0 \end{cases}
\end{align}

You are to take the limit of this function as $n\to\infty$.

Careful consideration is required, so first find out what happens if $\nu=1$ (say). Do you get a distribution function in the limit? Then proceed to argue for other values of $\nu$.

Comment: Would the answer be $\nu=\frac{1}{\beta}$ since $(1+\frac{-y^\beta}{n^{\nu\beta}})^n \to e^{-y^\beta}$ if $\nu\beta=1$?