# Convergence in distribution to a degenerate distribution

Tags: convergence, order-statistics

This question came up based on a disagreement I had with a TA. This was the specific example:

Let $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ be an iid random sample from a population with pdf $f(x)=3(1-x)^2, 0<x<1$. The $nth$ order statistic is represented as $X_{(n)}$.

Question: Find a constant $v$ such that $n^v(1-X_{(n)})$ converges in distribution.

I believe that the intent of the question was to prompt the invocation of Slutsky's theorem (or maybe not); however, to which distribution the presented snippet was supposed to converge was not specified. So I presented a lazy alternative answer as follows:

As the sample size approaches infinity, $X_{(n)}$ becomes arbitrarily close to 1. Therefore, we can simply set $v=0$ and the statement will converge to a degenerate distribution. In this case, the order statistic converges to 1, so with $v=0$, the statement converges to 0. I later realized that it actually converges to 1 after the transformation, which is reflected in the final degenerate distribution written toward the bottom of the question. I was surprised when the TA said that 0 is not a random variable or a distribution, and my answer made no sense. I second guessed myself and went further:

The cdf of the original distribution is $$F(x)=x^3-3x^2+3x$$ Using this, I derived the pdf of the order statistic,
$$f_{X_{(n)}}(x)=3n(x^2-2x+1)(x^3-3x^2+3x)^{n-1} $$
And the cdf of the order statistic, $$f_{X_{(n)}}(x)=(x^3-3x^2+3x)^n$$

I then used this to graph the cdf of the order statistic with $n=1, n=100, n=1,000,000,000$. Predictably, the graph showed the cdf getting thinner and steeper, until with huge samples it visually looks like a vertical line at $X_{(n)}=1$.

I reiterated my argument, and showed the visualization: it is converging to a degenerate distribution. Again, I was rebuffed. After pestering the TA and asking the instructor for the course, I still have no answer for why my answer was wrong, but I can't keep bothering them about it.

Can someone here tell me if my argument is solid, and if not, tell me specifically what I've done that is in error?

EDIT: Here is the final formalism that I gave to tie my argument together. Following Casella and Berger's definition,

> A sequence of random variables, $X_{1}, X_{2},...,$ converges in distribution to  a random variable $X$ if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} F_{X_n}(x) = F_X(x)$$ at all points $x$ where $F_X(x)$ is continuous

Since $$\lim_{n \to \infty} F_{X_(n)}(x) = 1$$
And we can define a degenerate variable $Y$ with the cdf
$$F_Y(x)=\begin{cases}1, & x\ge1\\ 0, & else \\ \end{cases}$$
We can say
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} F_{X_(n)}(x) = F_Y(x) $$

So by definition, $X_{(n)}$ converges in distribution to the degenerate distribution of $Y$.

EDIT: Adding a bounty to this, as it has become important. I did not formally perform the transformation $Y=1-X_(n)$ above, but doing so results in $Y$ having a distribution that still converges to the same degenerate distribution above. I was now told that my answer does not prove convergence in distribution at all. Question is answered if someone can definitively prove either 1) my answer is correct, and show exactly how you would have gone about proving it formally and rigorously, or 2) my answer is wrong, exactly why it is wrong, and prove any correct answer that uses degenerate distributions or degenerate variables if such an answer exists.

Comment: I do not know the flip-side of this anecdote, nor the motivations of your TA and instructor, nor have I parsed your argument in detail. Assuming you are seeing them during office hours, if they really are asserting things without any attempts whatsoever at substantiation or even engagement with your reasoning, then they are being derelict in their duties. And you are right to call them out on this, because it goes against the spirit of academia in general.

Comment: That being said, isn't the purpose of rescaling convergence in distribution statements so that you can find limiting distributions that are non-degenerate?

Comment: @microhaus I suppose so, but they should have said "find $v$ such that $n^v(1-X_{(n)})$ converges to a non-degenerate distribution," shouldn't they? I don't disagree that my answer was novel and is unlikely to have any applied purpose, but the question was theoretical and I gave an answer that is (I believe, unless someone here says otherwise) theoretically correct. I've edited the formal statement that I gave at the end to show the definition of convergence in distribution and show that my answer does fit the definition.

Comment: I think the word “degenerate” is causing problems here. “The variable which is always equal to 1” is constant but fine; neither this variable nor its distribution function is degenerate. By contrast, the functions $F(x)=0$ for all $x$ or $F(x)=(1+sgn(x))/2$ might be called degenerate distribution functions, since they have many of the right properties but are not actually the cdfs of any variables.

Comment: @MattF. I'm unsure of how it is causing problems. A random variable $Y$ is degenerate if it has cdf $$F_y(x)=\begin{cases}1, & x\ge y\\ 0, & else \\ \end{cases}$$ If you set $Y$ equal to any constant $y$ in that way, then it can also by definition be considered a degenerate random variable--specifically it has a univariate degenerate distribution. So a different random variable like $X_{(n)}$ may not be degenerate, but if it converges to a constant as $n$ approaches infinity, then it is converging to a degenerate.

Comment: Hmm...I guess I should say the term caused problems for me, more of  a mathematician than a statistician — it sounds like something which is not quite a variable. Perhaps that is a source of some difficulties in communication even if there is a standard meaning for the term in statistics which agrees with your usage.

Comment: I encounter the same problems often. To clarify, in statistics, the technical definition of a "random variable" is "a function from a sample space to the real numbers." If your sample space consists of a single value, and that value is mapped to 1, then the "random variable" is indistinguishable from a constant. Every constant $c$ is also a "random variable" mapping $c$ to 1, because $c$ has a probability of 1 to equal $c$.

Comment: Your answer is correct in the sense that $0$ is one possible value of $v$. Same exercise: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/438456/119261.

Comment: In the particular courses in intermediate theoretical statistics that I've been working from, and in the worked examples given, it has been explicitly established by the instructor that a convention when asked to find the limiting distribution is to rescale it so that the limiting distribution is non-degenerate. The reason they gave is that the primary function of finding a non-degenerate limiting distribution is that it may match a known distribution, thereby supplying an asymptotic approximation of probability statements about a particular quantity of interest.

Comment: Whether that is a general convention however is unknown to me.

Comment: Because this question appears to be about a *single distribution,* could you please explain why you refer to "parameter space" in the title and what you mean by that?

Comment: Edited out anything about parameter space in the title. Change it to whatever else you think is appropriate if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct (assuming that you have accurately transcribed the question). The proof:

Let $F_n(c)$ be the cdf of $(1 - X_{(n)})$, where $X_{(n)}$ is the greatest element in a sample of size $n$. Let $F(c)$ be the cdf for the constant 0 distribution.

For $c < 0$, of course $F_n(c) = 0 = F(c)$.

For $c > 1$, of course $F_n(c) = 1 = F(c)$.

For $0 < c \le 1$:

$$
\begin{align}
F_n(c) &= P(1 - X_{(n)} \le c) \\
&= P(X_{(n)} \ge 1-c) \\
&= 1-P(X_1 < 1-c, ..., X_n < 1-c) \\
&= 1 - P(X_1 < 1-c)^n \to 1 = F(c)
\end{align}
$$

And the case $c = 0$ doesn't matter, because $F$ isn't continuous at $0$.

If the people you are arguing with don't realise that convergence in distribution to a constant is a thing, you could point them to e.g. Wikipedia's [Proofs of convergence of random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution_to_a_constant_implies_convergence_in_probability) article.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "$c=0$ doesn't matter, because $F$ isn't continuous at $0$?" I get the feeling that needing to prove the part of the definition "at all points $x$ where $F_X(x)$ is continuous" was part of the confusion, but in my mind it was a trivial concern since a degenerate distribution is only defined on a single point. Therefore "at all points $x$ where $F_X(x)$ is continuous" is the same here as "at the one point $x$ where $F_X(x)$ is continuous."

Comment: The cdf of a real-valued random variable is defined on the entire real line, regardless of whether the random variable is degenerate. The cdf for this specific degenerate distribution is 0 for x<0 and 1 everywhere else. Its only point of discontinuity is therefore at 0.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the real issue here is that the TA does not like your answer because the purpose of scaling when seeking convergence results is to find an asymptotic distribution that is *non-degenerate*.  However, having said that, your answer is technically correct (the [best kind of correct](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo)?).  You can easily tighten up your argument by giving the explicit distribution of the quantity of interest and showing the limit of this distribution as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  I will show you how to do this here.

Take $v=0$ and denote the resulting quantity as $Y_n \equiv 1- X_{(n)} = 1 - \max (X_1,...,X_n)$.  Now observe that for all $0 \leqslant y \leqslant 1$ we have:

$$\begin{align}
F_{Y_n}(y) 
\equiv \mathbb{P}(Y_n \leqslant y) 
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}(Y_n > y) \\[12pt]
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}(\max (X_1,...,X_n) < 1-y) \\[6pt]
&= 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(X_i < 1-y) \\[4pt]
&= 1 - F_X(1-y)^n \\[12pt]
&= 1 - (3(1-y)-3(1-y)^2+(1-y)^3)^n \\[12pt]
&= 1 - ((3 - 3y) + (-3 + 6y - 3y^2) + (1 - 3y + 3y^2 - y^3))^n \\[12pt]
&= 1 - (1 - y^3)^n. \\[12pt]
\end{align}$$

Taking the limit (and now considering the broader range $y \in \mathbb{R}$) then gives:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_{Y_n}(y) = \mathbb{I}(y \geqslant 0),$$

which is the CDF of the point-mass distribution at zero.  So, you are correct that the distribution of $Y_{n}$ converges to a point-mass distribution at zero.  Of course, this is a degenerate distribution, and ideally we would like to get an asymptotic result giving convergence to a non-degenerate distribution.  I recommend you see if you can also derive the latter, which was presumably the intended goal of the exercise.